# how to configure sensu server with rabbitmq?

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq, sensu

I want to install `sensu-server` and `sensu-client` both on single node(ubuntu 14.04) for practical purpose. when i am using `redis` as transport it's working fine. but when i am trying to configure `rabbitmq` as transport than it's give me error.
my configuration structure is:

```
├── conf.d
│   ├── api.json
│   ├── check_apache.json
│   ├── client.json
│   ├── default_handler.json
│   ├── rabbitmq.json
│   ├── redis.json
│   └── transport.json
├── config.json.example
├── dashboard.d
├── extensions
├── plugins
│   └── check-apache.rb
├── ssl
│   ├── cert.pem
│   └── key.pem
└── uchiwa.json
```

/etc/sensu/uchiwa.json

```
{
    "sensu": [
        {
            "name": "Sensu",
            "host": "localhost",
            "ssl": false,
            "port": 4567,
            "path": "",
            "timeout": 5000
        }
    ],
    "uchiwa": {
        "port": 3000,
        "stats": 10,
        "refresh": 10000
    }
}
```

/etc/sensu/conf.d/api.json

```
{
    "api": {
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": 4567
    }
}
```

/etc/sensu/conf.d/client.json

```
{
    "client": {
        "name": "server",
        "address": "localhost",
        "subscriptions": [ "ALL" ]
    }
}
```

/etc/sensu/conf.d/rabbitmq.json

```
{
    "rabbitmq": {
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 5671,
        "vhost": "/sensu",
        "user": "sensu",
        "password": "pass",
        "heartbeat": 30,
        "prefetch": 50,
        "ssl": {
            "cert_chain_file": "/etc/sensu/ssl/cert.pem",
            "private_key_file": "/etc/sensu/ssl/key.pem"
        }
    }
}
```

/etc/sensu/conf.d/redis.json

```
{
    "redis": {
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": 6379
    }
}
```

/etc/sensu/conf.d/transport.json

```
{
    "transport": {
        "name": "rabbitmq",
        "reconnect_on_error": true
    }
}
```

when i replce `rabbitmq` to `redis` in `transport.json` file my setup working fine but in case of rabbitmq its not working.
in logs we get this error but username and password is correct that is provide in configuration file.

```
{"timestamp":"2017-03-21T18:44:28.167638+0000","level":"warn","message":"transport connection error","reason":"possible authentication failure. wrong credentials?","user":"sensu"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and have spent better part of my morning solving it. This problem arises when using SSL Certificate for RabbitMQ as a transport.

1) Without SSL:
One could achieve transportation via RabbitMQ by having the following configuration file config.json(/etc/sensu)

```
{
  "rabbitmq": {
    "host": "172.19.4.81",
    "port": 5671,
    "vhost": "/sensu",
    "user": "sensu",
    "password": "secret"
  },
 "transport": {
    "name": "rabbitmq",
    "reconnect_on_error": true
  },
  "api": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "bind": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": 4567
  },
"checks": {
    "check_http": {
      "type": "metric",
      "command": "/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_http -I 127.0.0.1",
      "interval": 40,
      "standalone": true,
    }
  },
  "client": {
    "subscriptions": [
      "production"
    ]
  }
}
```

This can be divided into different files and stored in /etc/sensu/conf.d. Sensu loads all the files present in conf.d and config.json. So location doesn't matter. It just suits me as all the configuration is in one place.

2) With SSL:
The exact cause of the problem might be located in /var/log/rabbitmq. However, for my case it showed

```
RABBITMQ ERROR LOG :
** Reason for termination =
** {function_clause,[{tls_v1,enum_to_oid,
[28],
[{file,"tls_v1.erl"},{line,404}]},
{ssl_handshake,'-dec_hello_extensions/2-blc$^1/1-0-',1,
[{file,"ssl_handshake.erl"},{line,1653}]},
{ssl_handshake,'-dec_hello_extensions/2-blc$^1/1-0-',1,
[{file,"ssl_handshake.erl"},{line,1653}]},
{ssl_handshake,dec_hello_extensions,2,
[{file,"ssl_handshake.erl"},{line,1653}]},
{tls_handshake,decode_handshake,3,
[{file,"tls_handshake.erl"},{line,182}]},
{tls_handshake,get_tls_handshake_aux,3,
[{file,"tls_handshake.erl"},{line,153}]},
{tls_connection,next_state,4,
[{file,"tls_connection.erl"},{line,454}]},
{gen_fsm,handle_msg,7,
[{file,"gen_fsm.erl"},{line,505}]}]}
```

and solution was upgrade to Erlang >= 17.5. as mentioned [here](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/issues/224) and in devops portal.

The erlang provided by epel repository is of version R16B03 and its better to remove and upgrade it. Since for some reason Erlang from the Erlang Solutions repository was not installed, I took Zero-dependency Erlang RPM for RabbitMQ provided by Rabbitmq. [erlang repo](https://github.com/rabbitmq/erlang-rpm) and configured the ssl as mentioned by sensu.(download the ssl certificates, provide exact path in rabbitmq and sensu configuration files)

a. Ssl certificates
Download it at

```
wget http://sensuapp.org/docs/1.0/files/sensu_ssl_tool.tar
tar -xvf sensu_ssl_tool.tar
```

Generate OpenSSL certificate authority and self-signed certificates using the Sensu SSL tool:

```
cd sensu_ssl_tool
./ssl_certs.sh generate
```

b. Place these certificates into directory which can be found by the Rabbitmq.

```
mkdir /etc/rabbitmq/ssl
cp server_key.pem /etc/rabbitmq/ssl/
cp server_cert.pem /etc/rabbitmq/ssl/
cp testca/cacert.pem /etc/rabbitmq/ssl/
```

RabbitMQ Config file if absent, can be created at /etc/rabbitmq as

```
/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
[
  {rabbit, [
     {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
     {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/cacert.pem"},
                    {certfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/cert.pem"},
                    {keyfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/key.pem"},
                    {versions, ['tlsv1.2']},
                    {ciphers,  [{rsa,aes_256_cbc,sha256}]},
                    {verify,verify_peer},   
                    {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}]}
   ]}
].
```

Now wherever the sensu components(client, api, server) are installed, the /etc/sensu/ssl folder should have the client/key.pem and client/cert.pem

```
cp client/key.pem client/cert.pem  /etc/sensu/ssl/
```

Now, These folders should be mentioned at sensu configuration file.

```
/etc/sensu/config.json
{
  "rabbitmq": {
    "host": "172.19.4.81",
    "port": 5672,
    "vhost": "/sensu",
    "user": "sensu",
    "password": "secret",
    "ssl": {
       "cert_chain_file": "/etc/sensu/ssl/cert.pem",
       "private_key_file": "/etc/sensu/ssl/key.pem"
     }
  },
  "transport": {
    "name": "rabbitmq",
    "reconnect_on_error": true
  },
  "api": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "bind": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": 4567
  },
"client": {
    "subscriptions": [
      "production"
    ]
  }
}
```

Default Port for rabbitmq is 5671 while with ssl is 5672.